# Availability check for OS version range

Tags: swift

In my app, I want to do things when the OS version is strictly in a specific range, and do something else when outside that range (either below or above it). The specific context is within a SwiftUI `@ViewBuilder`, but that's immaterial to the version check itself. I know I can accomplish that with something like this, for example:

```swift
if #available(iOS 16.4, *) {
    baseView
}
else if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
    baseView
        .extraModifierOnlyNecessaryBetweeniOS16And16Point4()
}
else {
    baseView
}
```

This applies the extra modifier only when the iOS version is in the range 16.0..<16.4, which is what I want. However, it's not very DRY, since I have to enumerate `baseView` for both the case where it's above and below that range, even though those cases are exactly equivalent

I was hoping I'd be able to do this, but it doesn't compile, as Swift says that `#available` and `#unavailable` can't be used in the same statement:

```swift
if #available(iOS 16, *), #unavailable(iOS 16.4) {
    baseView
        .extraModifierOnlyNecessaryBetweeniOS16And16Point4()
}
else {
    baseView
}
```

Is there a better way to accomplish this so that I don't have to handle the above and below cases separately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can do this：

```
    if #available(iOS 16, *) {
        if #unavailable(iOS 16.4) {
            return baseView
                .extraModifierOnlyNecessaryBetweeniOS16And16Point4()
        }
    }
    return baseView
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. "Maybe you can do this" isn't an explanation at all and makes it look like you're not actually sure whether this does indeed work. I presume you tried this before posting, and are thus sure that this works. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Comment: This is one of those answers that feels so obvious in hindsight. Thanks for showing me what I was missing! The only downside is that I have to sacrifice the `@ViewBuilder`